# Python hangs on lxml.etree.XMLSchema(tree) with apache + mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, lxml, xml-validation

Python hangs on

```
lxml.etree.XMLSchema(tree)
```

when I use it on apache server + mod_wsgi (Windows)

When I use Django dev server - all works fine

if you know about other nice XML validation solution against XSD, tell me pls

**Update:**

I'm using soaplib, which uses lxml

```
logger.debug("building schema...")
self.schema = etree.XMLSchema(etree.parse(f))

logger.debug("schema %r built, cleaning up..." % self.schema)
```

I see "building schema..." in apache logs, but I don't see "schema %r built, cleaning up..."

**Update 2:**
I built lxml 2.3 with MSVS 2010 visual C++; afterwards it crashes on this line

```
self.schema = etree.XMLSchema(etree.parse(f))
```

with  Unhandled exception at 0x7c919af2 in httpd.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000010.

Comment: (1) "hang up on etree.XMLSchema(tree)" conveys very little information -- what exactly do you mean? (2) I'm sure that the `lxml` developers would be very concerned to hear that there was a problem; `lxml` appears to be a very robust product, not prone to "hanging up" or breaking down -- consider reporting your problem on the `lxml` mailing list or bug tracker.

Comment: upd my question, add some info

Answer (score 3):

The work around that I used, is to set:

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

[More details can be found here.](https://techknowhow.library.emory.edu/blogs/branker/2010/07/30/django-lxml-wsgi-and-python-sub-interpreter-magic)

Comment: Link is broken. Some useful information on what this means here: https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIApplicationGroup

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (lxml 2.2.6, mod_wsgi 3.2). A work around for this is to pass a file or filename to the constructor: XMLSchema(file=).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on a Linux system. Try installing a more recent version of libxml2 and reinstalling lxml,  at least that's what did it for me.